# OS recommendation for Oracle XE on a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, oracle

I'm after advice on the best way to proceed, still new to some of this:

I'm looking into deploying a virtual machine solely for handling a copy of oracle database XE on it. Currently we are solely running a virtual windows 2012 R2 server with Microsoft Server SQL with all users running windows 10 pro connecting to it.

I've run into an issue where I'm most likely force to setup a lightweight oracle database. I'm trying to avoid expensive licensing and I'm after recommendations on what OS to use for the VM. I'm not too familiar with linux, but it might be the right avenue?

Users will be running a program that needs to connect to the oracle DB to query it and return results. This database will then be updated weekly having to download external data via oracle .dmp files (hence why I'm forced to use oracle).

Any recommendations, alternatives or pointers to head in the right direction are greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Questions regarding Software recommendations are off-topic here. You can head over to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), for example. As a pointer: [Oracle OS Checklist](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/operating-system-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation-on-linux.html#GUID-E5C0A90E-7750-45D9-A8BC-C7319ED934F0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Construct your VM with additional hardware configuration for future planning.

2.Install Cent OS with LVM Partion & SWAP (i.e SWAP = 2 X RAM )

3.Make sure minimal installation with required dependency have been installed.

4.Avoid GUI or any other unwanted heavy packages(Minimal installation may have only CLI).

5.For administration install Cockpit (Default port no 9090) i.e - lightweight + Fully manageable + VM + Docker + Storage + web-based interface.

6.Install your ORACLE XE with dependency.

Give this a try and post back with the errors you have identified and we shall try to resolve it.

Thanks,